# Xamarin.Forms CarouselView doesn't display ListViews

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried implementing a CarouselView that would display 2 ListViews on different screens. However, nothing seems to happen when I launch the app, the screen stays blank. I reduced the ListViews to basic lists of strings but I still couldn't manage to make the CarouselView work properly. What am I doing wrong?

**XAML:**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="Layout" Spacing="0">
    <forms:CarouselView x:Name="CarouselView"
                        ItemSelected="CarouselView_OnItemSelected"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding lists}">
        <forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </forms:CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

**C#:**

```
    lists = new ObservableCollection<ListView>
    {
        new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>{
                "test",
                "test"
            }
        },
        new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>{
                "test",
                "test"
            }
        }
    };
```

The code works as expected when I use Labels instead of ListViews inside the CarouselView. So the problem is probably in the way I define the ItemSource for the CarouselView. I just can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Did you manage do make it work ?

Comment: Yes, I tried creating the same component in the code-behind and for some reason it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is that you need to specify the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` or Vertical\Horizontal options of the `StackLayout` while using a CV. Use a `Grid` for more consistent behaviour